# Unintentionally overwriting Python 2.7 standard module - how to prevent?

Tags: python, module, python-import

I wanted to add some stuff to Python's logging module, so I created a separate module under package name "my", which is inside the project's directory (which is the first entry in `sys.path`). I also have another module of mine, which lives in that same space:

```
my
my.logging
my.something
```

Now I wanted to log stuff in `my.something` and added `import logging` to the file - but it seems Python loads `my.logging` instead of the standard module.

When reading the Python documentation (section 6.1.2. The Module Search Path), I thought I was safe:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path.

So a "standard module" is not a "built-in module"? I guess then, that I have to move the `my` modules out of the current directory - ? Other possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it says "built-in module", that line of docs is referring to modules actually compiled directly into the Python executable. You can see which ones those are in [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).

What you need to do is turn off implicit relative imports, which can be done on a per-file basis with the `absolute_import` future statement:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```